# JFrame is not showing properly on small screens

Tags: java, swing

[image]I am trying to create an application which could run on different screen sizes. I am trying it in Netbeans IDE. But what's happening is that my code is not working on as intended.

I found some solutions around it. And one of them was to use a Layout Manager so I did the same. But still nothing has changed due to that. Still the problem persist as same.
Please find below sample code.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testproject;

public class HomePage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form HomePage
     */
    public HomePage() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1366, 720));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1366, 720));

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(1167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField3.setText("jTextField1");

        jButton7.setText("jButton3");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 281, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(242, 242, 242))
        );

        jButton3.setText("jButton3");

        jButton4.setText("jButton3");

        jButton5.setText("jButton3");

        jButton6.setText("jButton3");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 288, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 281, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 283, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 301, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HomePage().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Please tell me the mistakes in the above mentioned code, if any. And suggest any solution around it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is specific problem are you having on small screens? It might help to have some images here.

Comment: there is no image in my code. Just UI is not properly visible on different screen size

Comment: The issue is you are using the layout manager incorrectly ...

Comment: Have you tried changing your setPrefferedSize parameters?

Comment: @Constantin : so what is the correct way to use layout manager?

Comment: @LaneL yeah.. but nothing happens

Comment: The right way is for your widgets to be re-positioned as the window is resized...these are fixed in place ... If you draw me a picture of how you want these widgets positioned on a form, ill do it for you

Comment: @Constantin i understand.. but how can i achieve that?

Comment: @Constantin please run the same code and this what i exactly want.

Comment: @Constantin Or give me any other example code that run on all screen sizes

Comment: OK, I am coding it now ...

Comment: should learn to code gui's before you start using a builder tbh

Comment: @HuangChen I agree, in fact, all he needs to master is BorderLayout and GridLayout and pretty much any sort of layout can be achieved

Comment: @Constantin I prefer absolute since I do w/e with it but those 2 are my other go to's

Comment: Absolute positioning for GUI controls is a no-no when using Swing. The only time you really need absolute positioning is for custom painting to a JPanel canvas for stuff like games or building graphical editors and such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]As I told you before, you can achieve almost any sort of Layout using only `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout`. Master those two layout managers and you don't need the others. Here is my final version. Please refer to the tutorials here for a greater understanding of Layout Managers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

```
            import java.awt.BorderLayout;
            import java.awt.Color;
            import java.awt.Component;
            import java.awt.Dimension;
            import java.awt.GridLayout;

            import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
            import javax.swing.JButton;
            import javax.swing.JFrame;
            import javax.swing.JLabel;
            import javax.swing.JPanel;
            import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
            import javax.swing.JTextField;
            import javax.swing.JTree;
            import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
            import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
            import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

            public class FrameDemo extends JFrame {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public FrameDemo() {
                    super("Frame Demo");
                    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    getContentPane().add(new NorthPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    getContentPane().add(new CenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    getContentPane().add(new SouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                //          Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                //          int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
                //          int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
                //          setSize(xSize,ySize);

                    pack();
                    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            JFrame frame = new FrameDemo();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });
                } 
            }

            class NorthPanel extends JPanel {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public NorthPanel() {
                    super(new BorderLayout());
                    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

                    add(getHeaderPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                }

                private Component getHeaderPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                    panel.add(new JLabel("XXXXXX Enterprises", SwingConstants.CENTER));
                    panel.add(new JLabel("XXX, Industria; Area - II, XXXXXXXXX", SwingConstants.CENTER));

                    return panel;
                }

                private Component getButtonPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));

                    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                    buttons.add(new JButton("Admin"));
                    buttons.add(new JButton("Exit"));

                    panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
                    return panel;
                }
            }

            class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                private static final Dimension PANEL_SIZE = new Dimension(640, 480);

                public CenterPanel() {
                    super(new BorderLayout());
                    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

                    add(getSearchFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    add(getResultsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }

                private Component getSearchFieldsPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                    panel.add(new JLabel("Sales Inventory", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    panel.add(getFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    panel.add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                    return panel;
                }

                private Component getResultsPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                    panel.add(getHeaderPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    panel.add(new JScrollPane(new JTree()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    panel.add(getAnotherButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                    return panel;
                }

                private Component getHeaderPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));

                    JLabel label = new JLabel("Customers", SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    label.setOpaque(true);
                    label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


                    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    return panel;
                }

                private Component getFieldsPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));

                    panel.add(new LabeledField("Name :  "));
                    panel.add(new LabeledField("Firm Name :  "));
                    panel.add(new LabeledField("City :  "));
                    panel.add(new LabeledField("Mobile :  "));

                    return panel;
                }

                private Component getButtonPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
                    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                    buttons.add(new JButton("Reset"));
                    buttons.add(new JButton("Search"));

                    panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
                    return panel;
                }

                private Component getAnotherButtonPanel() {
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
                    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                    buttons.add(new JButton("Next"));

                    panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
                    return panel;
                }

                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return PANEL_SIZE;
                }

                public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                    return PANEL_SIZE;
                }

                public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                    return PANEL_SIZE;
                }
            }

            class SouthPanel extends JPanel {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public SouthPanel() {
                    super(new GridLayout());

                    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

                    add(new JButton("Sales Inventory"));
                    add(new JButton("Customer"));
                    add(new JButton("Stock Inventory"));
                    add(new JButton("Reports"));
                }
            }

            class LabeledField extends JPanel {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public LabeledField(String label) {
                    super(new BorderLayout());

                    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    add(getLabel(label), BorderLayout.WEST);
                    add(getEntry(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }

                private Component getLabel(String caption) {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(caption, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
                    return label;
                }

                private Component getEntry() {
                    return new JTextField();
                }
            }
```

This is output
[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;

public class FrameDemo extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FrameDemo() {
        super("Frame Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getContentPane().add(new NorthPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(new CenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(new SouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //          Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        //          int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
        //          int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
        //          setSize(xSize,ySize);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new FrameDemo();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    } 
}

class NorthPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NorthPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        add(getHeaderPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private Component getHeaderPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        panel.add(new JLabel("XXXXXX Enterprises", SwingConstants.CENTER));
        panel.add(new JLabel("XXX, Industria; Area - II, XXXXXXXXX", SwingConstants.CENTER));

        return panel;
    }

    private Component getButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Admin"));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Exit"));

        panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
        return panel;
    }
}

class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Dimension PANEL_SIZE = new Dimension(640, 480);

    public CenterPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        add(getSearchFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new NewPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(getResultsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private Component getSearchFieldsPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Sales Inventory", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(getFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(getButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    private Component getResultsPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(getHeaderPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(new JTree()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(getAnotherButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    private Component getHeaderPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 10, 0));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Customers", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return panel;
    }

    private Component getFieldsPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));

        panel.add(new LabeledField("Name :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Firm Name :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("City :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Mobile :  "));

        return panel;
    }

    private Component getButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Reset"));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Search"));

        panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
        return panel;
    }

    private Component getAnotherButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Next"));

        panel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
        return panel;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return PANEL_SIZE;
    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return PANEL_SIZE;
    }

    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return PANEL_SIZE;
    }
}

class SouthPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SouthPanel() {
        super(new GridLayout());

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        add(new JButton("Sales Inventory"));
        add(new JButton("Customer"));
        add(new JButton("Stock Inventory"));
        add(new JButton("Reports"));
    }
}

class LabeledField extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LabeledField(String label) {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(getLabel(label), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(getEntry(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private Component getLabel(String caption) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(caption, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
        return label;
    }

    private Component getEntry() {
        return new JTextField();
    }
}

class NewPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NewPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 10));       
        add(getTopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new NewBottomPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);     
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(350, 300);
    }

    private Component getTopPanel() {
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Design ID :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Thickness :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("   Finish :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField(" Quantity :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("     Rate :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("     Size :  "));

        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(getTopButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return container;
    }

    private Component getTopButtonPanel() {
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0));

        container.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        container.add(new JButton("Add Item"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        return container;
    }
}

class NewBottomPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NewBottomPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0);
        Border redLineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1);
        Border compounded = new CompoundBorder(emptyBorder, redLineBorder);
        setBorder(compounded);      
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(getTopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

    private Component getTopPanel() {
        JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0));
        container.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Design ID :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Thickness :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("   Finish :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField(" Quantity :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("     Rate :  "));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("     Size :  "));

        container.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);       
        return container;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I hope you get the idea but if you're still confused tell me

Comment: hmm.. i will analyize your code. i have run that code.

Comment: it works properly. where you set the frame size. i need main frame size maximum the screen size.

Comment: can you describe the code so that i understand easily and use that approach in my code.

Comment: i added part for fullscreen

Comment: I am using nested JPanels and placing them in the contentPane() of your JFrame

Comment: thanks for help.. i will try to use same approach in my application. will ask you if i need your help!!

Comment: Please study the tutorisal of two layout managers first ... BorderLayout and GridLayout .... do not worry about the other ones and then study my code

Comment: As link sent by you. there is mentioned that in netbeans IDE there is not need to add layout in code. it will automatically add that. so i have create code using netbeans IDE. so why this code is not running on small screens.??

Comment: I don't have net beans ide, sorry. My code works fine as it is

Comment: hi.. I have study the layout managers refer by you. And I further started to made my screen. But I'm stuck at one point that is how can I start my panel from a specific position in jframe?? I just want to make the gui of screen that I have attach new image with this. Kindly refer me and solve my problem. It will be great!

Comment: This looks very different than your previous request. I will send it but this is last time.

Comment: Not a problem. . But please send me. I'm in big problem.  Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I already sent it 3 hours ago... Please accept the answer so we can close this question, Thank you

Comment: Hi Constantin !  Referring to your example and tutorial link.. i have made many JFrame having layout managers. Your example is very helpful for me. but in my project, I'm stuck on one Frame. I'm not able to create that frame using layout managers. so i need your help. Can you please help me out. It would be great for me. your help is highly appreciated. Please.

Comment: The rest of the code is same. only centeredPanel need to be changed. Please!

Comment: Just put a JTable in there instead of a JTree. What's so hard about that? That has nothing to do with LayoutManager code

Comment: Arrey! i'm not talking about the above screen shot. Above screen shot is very good.

Comment: i had made very screen based on that coding.

Comment: i'm talking about another screen shot that has only centerPanel different from above screen shot.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking sorry. I think I have answered your question. Please accept it already

Comment: yeah.. i accept your answer. your answer is very helpful for me. i'm talking about another problem. please help me out.

Comment: You didnt accept this one yet...Once accepted, post your new request in a new question, ok?

Comment: but my question is related to this. thats why i had posted in this to you.

Comment: i had uploaded that screen shot about which i am talking.

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow.. thats why i don't know from where i need to accept that answer. thanks.

Comment: I will look at it later ... I have to go now

Comment: ok.. not a problem.. but please help me when you get free.. when i supposed to get help from your side?

Comment: Hi Constantin !! Could you please help me out from this problem? i am trying to make that centered jpanel from 7 days but unable to make. uour help is higly appreciated.

Comment: I told you to study BorderLayout and GridLayout. Master them fully before looking at my code...That is the last code I am giving you ... Good luck